# Seq2Seq RNN with an AttentionLayer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

In many Sequence to Sequence machine learning tasks, an Attention Mechanism is incorporated.
Before Transformer Networks, introduced in the paper: [Attention Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf), mainly RNNs were used to model seq2seq models.
An attention score was generated along with a new hidden state ([this blog illustrates the process very well](https://towardsdatascience.com/attn-illustrated-attention-5ec4ad276ee3)). So, basically, the attention scores were dependent both on time and on an input sequence element. I am interested in whether it is possible to model this relationship by Mathematica LongShortTermMemoryLayer and AttentionLayer.

More specifically, I am interested in recreating the famous handwritten synthesis network by [Alex Graves](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0850).
[image] 
As you can see from the architecture, after the first LSTM layer, 
there is an Attention mechanism (the original name mentioned in the paper is "local window layer"): which for each timepoint and character models the belief of writing that character. So, is it possible to model the "local window layer " by an AttentionLayer? 
And if yes, then how it should be combined with an LSTM layer, what 
should be the keys, values, and queries in this case?

I would be grateful for any help.